# Формирование данных формы посредством drag&drop в html5

Tags: css3, html5, drag-n-drop

Я далек от профессионального использования html5, но возникла необходимость в следующем:

- на html страничке нужны две области. Одна с компонентами рецепта, в другую эти компоненты пользователь должен перетаскивать
- Вторая область - это форма или я не знаю что, но информацию о своем содержимом она должна будет как-то отправить на сервер. Элементов из первой области в нее можно поместить сколько угодно
- На всякий случай укажу, что сами перетаскиваемые компоненты должны будут содержать информацию о количестве компонента (мл, гр)

Подскажите, как это можно реализовать на html. Библиотеки, гайды, все что угодно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. DD пример:

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}
function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
```

```css
#div1 {
  width: 350px;
  height: 70px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<br>
<div id="drag1"  draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" >1234567</div>
<div id="drag2"  draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" >ЙЦУКЕН</div>
<div id="drag3"  draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" >информация о количестве компонента (мл, гр)</div>
</body>
</html>
```

2. Вот с div нужно подумать, чтобы отправлять в форме почтой через php и т.д.

> Подскажите, как это можно реализовать на html. Библиотеки, гайды, все
>   что угодно

Источник: HTML5 Drag and Drop https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp

===============================================

В общем), вот такой костыль рабочий получился:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="rus">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<head>
    <script>
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}
function drag(ev) {
ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}
function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));  
  var ddd = document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML;
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = ddd.replace(/<[^>]*>/g, " ");
  /*Или так эту функцию изобразить:
  function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));  
  var nnn = document.getElementById("div1").innerText;
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = nnn;  
}  
  */
}
    </script>   
<style>
    #div1 {
  width: 350px;
  height: 70px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<?="Отослано: ".$_POST['result']?>
<form name="forma" action="" method="post">
<textarea id="result" style="display: none" name="result"></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Отправить">
</form>

<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<div id="drag1"  draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" >1234567</div>
<div id="drag2"  draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" >ЙЦУКЕН</div>
<div id="drag3"  draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" >информация о количестве компонента (мл, гр)</div>

</body>
</html>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо! Именно то, что нужно, код работает

Comment: )Пожалуйста, рад!